# Is It possible to navigate or push from splash screen to admin screen or user screen based on the user role?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using Flutter and firebase to create a web application.
Below are the dependencies:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.3
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
```

Below are the script versions on web/index.html:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

I am trying to navigate the user after login with the email and password method. The user should be navigate to `admin page` or `user page` depends on the `user role` on `cloud Firestore`. After login The user from login page it will navigate to the `splash screen` where the user should be decided to navigate to next page depends on the user role. Its working up to splash screen but I am unable to do what I want todo, the pages are not to be navigated. Please let me know is this a correct way and Please give me a solution.
Below is my testing code on splash screen:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webfire/admin_screen.dart';
import 'package:webfire/home_screen.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  String role = 'user';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkRole();
  }

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  
  void _checkRole() async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    //User user = auth.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get();

    setState(() {
      role = snap['role'];
    });

    if (role == 'user') {
      navigateNext(const HomeScreen());
    } else if (role == 'admin') {
      navigateNext(const AdminScreen());
    }
  }

  void navigateNext(Widget route) {
    Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => route));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
          Text('Welcome'),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Errors:
opening utils.dart and showing :`return util.promiseToFuture(thenable);`

> Below is the Edited Code as per 1st Answer:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webfire/admin_screen.dart';
import 'package:webfire/home_screen.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  String role = 'user';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkRole();
  }

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  void _checkRole() async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    //User user = auth.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .get();

    setState(() {
      role = snap['role'];
    });

    // if (role == 'user') {
    //   navigateNext(const HomeScreen());
    // } else if (role == 'admin') {
    //   navigateNext(const AdminScreen());
    // }
  }

  void navigateNext(Widget route) {
    Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => route));
    });
  }

  // @override
  // Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //   return Scaffold(
  //       body: Center(
  //     child: Column(
  //       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  //       children: const [
  //         Text('Welcome to my project'),
  //       ],
  //     ),
  //   ));
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          if (role == 'user') const HomeScreen(),
          if (role == 'admin') const AdminScreen(),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

> below is Exception Error:

```
Exception has occurred.
"Error: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderStack#197ec NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
  creator: Stack ← _FloatingActionButtonTransition ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ← AnimatedBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#c955e ink renderer] ← NotificationListener<LayoutChangedNotification> ← PhysicalModel ← AnimatedPhysicalModel ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
  constraints: MISSING
  size: MISSING
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight
  textDirection: ltr
  fit: loose
Unfortunately, this object's geometry is not known at this time, probably because it has never been laid out. This means it cannot be accurately hit-tested.
If you are trying to perform a hit test during the layout phase itself, make sure you only hit test nodes that have completed layout (e.g. the node's children, after their layout() method has been called).
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:61527/dart_sdk.js:5061:11)
```

> Below is debug error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:51157/0tP91b-9bJU%3D/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51157/0tP91b-9bJU=/ws
 Running with sound null safety
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:51157/0tP91b-9bJU=/ws

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderFlex#5be33 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=681.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
The exact size it was given was: Size(681.0, Infinity)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2205:9                                                                             <fn>
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 2298:14                                                                            debugAssertDoesMeetConstraints
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 1991:7                                                                             <fn>
packages/flutter/src/rendering/box.dart 1992:14                                                                            set size
packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart 403:5                                                                    performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 1388:11                                                                      performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart 56:10                                                                    layoutChild
packages/flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart 829:43                                                                            [_computeSizes]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart 931:32                                                                            performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart 437:7                                                                      performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart 171:10                                                                   layoutChild
packages/flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart 1097:7                                                                         performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart 240:7                                                                    [_callPerformLayout]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart 404:14                                                                   performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 1388:11                                                                      performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 3420:14                                                                      performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart 116:7                                                                        performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1858:7                                                                          layout
packages/flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart 745:14                                                                           performLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1713:7                                                                          [_layoutWithoutResize]
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 885:17                                                                          flushLayout
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 453:19                                                                         drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 883:13                                                                           drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 319:5                                                                          [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1143:15                                                                        [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1080:9                                                                         handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 996:5                                                                          [_handleDrawFrame]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1003:13           invoke
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 157:5             invokeOnDrawFrame
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine.dart 440:45                                <fn>
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#95e25 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox#95e25 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=681.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    size: Size(681.0, Infinity)
    child 1: RenderPositionedBox#0a91e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        alignment: Alignment.center
        textDirection: ltr
        widthFactor: expand
        heightFactor: expand
        child: RenderFlex#1cdfb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            direction: vertical
            mainAxisAlignment: center
            mainAxisSize: max
            crossAxisAlignment: center
            verticalDirection: down
            child 1: RenderParagraph#768de NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
                parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                textAlign: start
                textDirection: ltr
                softWrap: wrapping at box width
                overflow: clip
                locale: en_US
                maxLines: unlimited
                text: TextSpan
                    debugLabel: (englishLike body1 2014).merge(blackRedmond bodyText2)
                    inherit: false
                    color: Color(0xdd000000)
                    family: Segoe UI
                    size: 14.0
                    weight: 400
                    baseline: alphabetic
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none
                    "You have logged in Successfuly"
            child 2: RenderConstrainedBox#f5889 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
                parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=50.0)
            child 3: RenderConstrainedBox#6f662 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=150.0, h=60.0)
                child: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#68b39 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
                    parentData: <none>
                    constraints: MISSING
                    semantic boundary
                    size: MISSING
    child 2: RenderStack#197ec NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.floatingActionButton
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight
        textDirection: ltr
        fit: loose
        child 1: RenderTransform#402cb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
            parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            size: MISSING
            transform matrix: [0] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[1] 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
            origin: null
            alignment: Alignment.center
            textDirection: ltr
            transformHitTests: true
            child: RenderTransform#03a78 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
                parentData: <none>
                constraints: MISSING
                size: MISSING
                transform matrix: [0] 0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[1] -0.7,0.7,0.0,0.0
[2] 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0
[3] 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
                origin: null
                alignment: Alignment.center
                textDirection: ltr
                transformHitTests: true
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
Assertion failed:
!_debugDuringDeviceUpdate
is not true

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Screen Shot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you might have fixed but let me share my solution you can upgrade on this.

**SplashScreen Page and Model class**

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_dynamic_links/admin_page.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_dynamic_links/user_page.dart';

    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      final SplashScreenModel model;
      const SplashScreen({
        Key? key,
        required this.model,
      }) : super(key: key);

      @override
      State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
    }

    class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        checkRoleAndNavigate();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Text('You can show loading indicator or App logo'),
        );
      }

      Future<void> checkRoleAndNavigate() async {
        final Role role = await widget.model.init();
        if (role == Role.admin) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AdminPage()));
        } else if (role == Role.user) {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => UserPage()));
        }
      }
    }

    class SplashScreenModel {
      //as it takes little time to check no need timer
      Future<Role> init() async {
        final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        final snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user!.uid)
            .get();
        final role = snap['role'];
        if (role == 'user') {
          return Role.user;
        } else {
          return Role.admin;
        }
      }
    }

    enum Role { user, admin }
```

**User Page**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class UserPage extends StatelessWidget {
      const UserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Text('User Page'),
        );
      }
    }
```

**Admin Page**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class AdminPage extends StatelessWidget {
      const AdminPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Text('Admin Page'),
        );
      }
    }
```

======================================================

To show splash for 5 seconds or something

```
        checkRoleAndNavigate() {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((value) async {
          final Role role = await widget.model.init();
          if (role == Role.admin) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AdminPage()));
          } else if (role == Role.user) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => UserPage()));
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: I am trying it and let you know and thank you for the response.

Comment: I am navigating this splashscreen() from login screen. Previously used ''const SplashScreen(),'' But in the new splash screen with odel as per your reference. how can call the splash screen from login screen now.

Comment: showing on view problem: The named parameter 'model' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.dartmissing_required_argument
SplashScreen SplashScreen({Key? key, required SplashScreenModel model})

Comment: SplashScreen(model: SplashScreenModel(),), pass the class initialization from where you calling SplashScreen page

Comment: This is an example to navigate between the pages based on the Role you have to modified the logic and UI according to you

Answer (score 0):

You can't navigate (or return a Future) using `Navigator` when an app is building, a better approach would be to show the relevant screen based on the role.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: const [
           if (role == 'user') 
               const HomeScreen(),
           if (role == 'admin') 
              const AdminScreen(),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edited code as per your answer. Its showing some error. on debug console. I think its stocked in the Splash screen not going to home  or admin screens.

Comment: I am new to Flutter and firebase. Is my splash screen and role based method approach which is I am trying to do, Good or not ? In case it is not a good approach, Please suggest me a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

To route the user to the correct page based on their role, you can perform the following two common steps:

- Create or update the database document associated with a user.
- Use custom claims in the `FireStore Authentication token` for each
  user.

Here are some videos that could help you to achieve your main goal:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=Tyk0Qte0moY - Flutter Role-based authorization with Firestore

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFlHzF5U-HA - Setting up role based access control

Here is also additional documentation to review for the database rules:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions
- https://gist.github.com/sararob/331760829a9dcb4be3e7

Blog post: http://curlybrackets.co/blog/2016/03/07/implementing-roles-in-firebase/